# Does @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) runs the methods with @Test annotation in the same class concurrently?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Does @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) runs the methods with @Test annotation in the same class concurrently?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

@Test
public void testA(){}

@Test
public void testB(){}

@Test
public void testB(){}

}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: To see for yourself if it does, create a static synchronized method inside your test class, and have all the `@Test` methods call it. Have the method do a `sleep(1000L)` just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks! I was testing others application in a wrong perspective.